# get Object based on relational child object - parse server

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I have `_User`, `company` and`job` class.Company class has one column type `Relation` pointing `_User` class and Job class has one column type `Relation` pointing `company` class.

Now I want my users to create job where parse cloud code will find the user's company based on his user object `req.user`

for example,
company `CP` belongs to user `U`. when `U` will hit the job create endpoint with his session token, a new document in the job table will be added with company `CP`. Here's what i've tried but it returns all the company list

```
let query = new Parse.Query('company');
user.get('vz5tF2g4Pi')
 .then(u => {
   //query.
   return query.find('users', u)
})
.then(rs => console.log('.... ', rs))
.catch(err => console.log('err ', err))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to fetch the user first and got the API wrong

```
const user = new Parse.User();
user.id = 'vz5tF2g4Pi'
var query = new Parse.Query('company');
query.equalTo('users', user);
query.find().then(rs => console.log('.... ', rs))
            .catch(err => console.log('err ', err))
```

And you should be good